# scala reserved keywords match

Tags: scala, match

I am importing in a Scala project a java class which uses the keyword `match` . 
I need to override the method `match` in my Scala code.

```
class Foo extends JavaClass {

      override def match (String str) : Boolean = { .... }}
```

But this is not working, the error is:

> identifier expected but 'match' found

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match` is a [reserved](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-scala/9781449368814/apa.html) word so you're not allowed to modify it.  You just have to call it something else.

Perhaps `` def `match`(str: String)... ``

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
override def `match` (str: String) : Boolean = { .... }}
```